# Ubuntu 16.04 unable to open after update and upgrade task, how to resolve that issue?

Tags: 16.04, updates, update-manager

I use Aspire e15 es-511-p7ux accer laptop. With Intel quad core procedure. I unable to explain what exactly happen with my laptop.
I have dual boot Linux mint and Ubuntu. Linux mint is ok but Ubuntu not starting.
Here is photo of screen.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the GRUB menu at startup, you should start Ubuntu in recovery mode. Later, once it's booted (if it does, I don't want to assume), select an older kernel (likely the second to most recent one) to install and reboot.

Comment: I did it but it's failed to open new Ubuntu and old one also have freezing problem. But hope that old Ubuntu still running from grub.